# Is it possible to import SVG assets as a sequence for UI animation?

Tags: javascript, svg-filters, spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to import a sequence of assets(svg) to create an interactive UI. I'm able to do that with a png file but not with svg as you can see from the image attached. [Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DM9x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

With SVG it is much more effective to generate animation by manipulating the SVG file itself in realtime, with a library such as Velocity.js or Anime.js.

Because SVG is a [declerative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) data format, but PNG is [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), making animations out of them require radically different approaches. An animation technique known as [tweening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening) (which is very convenient for UI animation) is very powerful with SVG, but you can always generate a PNG image from an SVG though and use a PNG approach.